# How to implement generalisation in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin, uml, erd

I'm slightly new to MySQL and was wondering how to implement a generalisation association in SQL.

In my UML diagram I have a user with two sub-classes (Employee and Manager) that inherit all the attributes of User.

How would I go about writing this in SQL?

Thanks!!

[UML Generalisation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qfh0g.png)

Comment: What is wrong with your current design?

Comment: Employee and Manager "detail" tables shouldn't need their own separate PK values unless a User can have multiple Manager (or Employee) "details"; also I would think all managers are employees, but that could just be a naming vagary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are different ways to implement a generalization. One is to create a table that has all the generalized attributes, plus those of he inheriting classes along with an enumeration, telling which of the specialized attributes are valid. You will have a naming convention too to identify the attributes from the specializing classes. E.g. if your `Employee` had an attribute `degree` you'd name it `emp_degree` or the like.

A second way would be to have a `User` table and using foreign keys in `Employee` etc.

All depends on the requirements. There is no silver bullet.